# How can I create a shapefile from a .dwg file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, autocad, dwg

I'm working on extracting various weather data from a specified region for a project. I've obtained the map for the area and isolated my part specifically on AutoCAD. Now I have a .dwg file which contains the boundaries I want to work with in ArcMap.

I was wondering how I can convert this .dwg file into a .shp file to use it as a mask file, with the coordinates and geographic coordinate system, etc. included.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CAD to Geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/cad-to-geodatabase.htm):

> Reads a CAD dataset and creates feature classes of the drawing. The
> feature classes are written to a geodatabase feature dataset.

Then export/convert the file geodatabase feature classes to shapefiles